# Java Simple-XML Deserializing

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the following XML:

```
<jdownloader>
    <package
        package_eta="~"
        package_linksinprogress="0"
        package_linkstotal="5"
        package_loaded="0 B"
        package_name="Unchecked"
        package_percent="0.00"
        package_size="0 B"
        package_speed="0 B"
        package_todo="0 B" >

        <file
            file_hoster="hoster_name"
            file_name="name"
            file_package="Unchecked"
            file_percent="0.09"
            file_speed="0"
            file_status="[Aborted] " >

            <file
                file_hoster="hoster_name"
                file_name="name"
                file_package="Unchecked"
                file_percent="0.03"
                file_speed="0"
                file_status="[Aborted] " >

                <file
                    file_hoster="hoster_name"
                    file_name="name"
                    file_package="Unchecked"
                    file_percent="0.05"
                    file_speed="0"
                    file_status="[Aborted] " >
                </file>
            </file>
        </file>
    </package>
</jdownloader>
```

I can't seem to get simple-xml to deserialize this the way I want.

I need to get an object for package (will be multiple packages in each xml), and a list of file objects as a child of the package object.
The XML can't be changed, and it seems each file element is nested under the previous file element, instead of all under the package parent.

The code I have for this so far is:

```
@Root(name = "jdownloader")
public class DownloadsModel {

    @ElementList(name="package")
    public List<PackageModel> Package;

}


@Root(name = "package")
public class PackageModel {

    @ElementList(name="file")
    public List<FileModel> file;

    @Attribute
    public String package_eta;

    @Attribute
    public String package_linksinprogress;

    @Attribute
    public String package_linkstotal;

    @Attribute
    public String package_loaded;

    @Attribute
    public String package_name;

    @Attribute
    public String package_percent;

    @Attribute
    public String package_size;

    @Attribute
    public String package_speed;

    @Attribute
    public String package_todo;

}

@Root(name = "file")
public class FileModel {

    @Attribute
    public String file_hoster;

    @Attribute
    public String file_name;

    @Attribute
    public String file_package;

    @Attribute
    public String file_percent;

    @Attribute
    public String file_speed;

    @Attribute
    public String file_status;

}
```

When Simple-XML tries to deserialize the xml, its looking for the file elements' attributes in the package class.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

To start off, try replacing:

```
public class PackageModel {

         @ElementList(name="file")
         public List<FileModel> file;
```

with this

```
public class PackageModel {

         @ElementList(name="file", inline=true)
         public List<FileModel> file;
```

You can then do away with your multiple `FileModel` definitions.

More details [here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#inline).

Answer (score 0):

Your model is thats like

```
@Root(name = "package")
public class DownloadsModel {

    @ElementList(name = "package", inline = true)
    public List<PackageModel> Package;
}
```

Package:

```
@Root(name = "package")
public class PackageModel {

    @ElementList(name = "file", inline = true)
    public List<FileModel> file;
    ....
}
```

and for file (The XML can't be changed, and it seems each file element is nested under the previous file element, instead of all under the package parent)

```
@Root(name = "file")
public class FileModel {

@ElementList(name = "file", inline = true, required = false)
public List<FileModel> file;

@Attribute
public String file_hoster;

....
}
```